# Website gets redirected to 127.0.0.1 occasionally

Tags: networking, routing, localhost, hosts-file, loopback

I am trying to access [AirAsia's Web Check-in Page](http://checkin.airasia.com). Occasionally I can access it. However, most of the time I get redirected to 127.0.0.1. Could this be an ISP issue?

Details:

1. My hosts file is clean.
2. Others on the network also faces this problem.
3. My router is also clean. I still can access the page occasionally.
4. Using another mobile data connection allows me to access the page.

Comment: How this question is different from the rest: I only get redirected OCCASIONALLY but not all the time.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an ISP issue, but it could equally be a problem with a load balancer / director at Air Asia - and unless your ISP is doing some kind of proxying, its more likely to be Air Asia.

It is also possible that its a problem with the DNS servers you are using.